# How to use grpcurl in mac?

Tags: macos, grpc

How to use grpcurl in mac?

```
$ grpcurl --plaintext $(minikube ip):31001 yages.Echo.Ping
```

Tried following:

`brew tap grpc/grpc`

`brew install --with-plugins grpc`

Above does not add `grpcurl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

`brew install grpcurl` works now on mac.

=====

(Alternative version)

If go is not already installed:
`brew install go`

then:

```
go get github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl
go install github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl/cmd/grpcurl
```

ref: https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl

Answer (score 1):

`brew install grpcurl` works on Mac

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/grpcurl

Comment: I still get `zsh: command not found: grpccurl`. I recall setting a Go path was required? EDIT: Found it, needed to add this to my .zshrc file -> ```export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH```